# Is there any way to tell my iPhone to use a different mic than my AirPods?

Tags: iphone, ipad, audio, microphone, airpods

I use my AirPods for streaming on YouTube. I don’t own a computer only an iPad and iphone. A friend bought me a usb mic not thinking that I don’t own a computer. So I bought a usb to lightning adapter. The mic has power but the sound comes from my AirPods not the mic.

I only have wired and wireless AirPods and both have built in mics.

I want sound in from the wired mic and sound out to the AirPods over Bluetooth.

Can I split the audio and use the better mic for recording?

Comment: Is the microphone working on your iPhone when your AirPods aren't connected ?

Comment: Yes. Everything works fine. I bought a lightning to usb and lightning adapter that way I could countinue charging the phone while using the mic. The mic lights up but doesn’t make sound that I can hear whether the AirPods are connected or not. I even tried putting the mic settings to the right side AirPod and putting that one in the charging case and just using the left side. That didn’t work either.

Comment: Adapter         
https://www.amazon.com/HENKUR-Adapter-Charging-Interface-Compatible/dp/B07GJ9TYWP/ref=sr_1_9?keywords=Lightning+to+usb+lightning&qid=1581790937&s=electronics&sr=1-9

Comment: The microphone WORKS. It just doesn’t work when I’m using the AirPods. I need them to work together in order to stream with the new mic. If it can’t work, ok, but if it can, I’d much rather use the microphone.

Answer (score 1):

Only in Live Listen mode (an Accessibility feature under Settings : Control Center).

But in general, no.  iOS devices switch both audio routes (in and out) to the last connected audio output device.  AirPods in your case.